# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, next.js

Error -

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Code -

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react"

function login({ providers }) {
  return (
    <div>
    <img className='w-52 mb-5' src='https://links.papareact.com/9xl' alt=''/>
    {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
      <div>
        <button>Login with {provider.name}</button>
      </div>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default login

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  };  
}
```

Comment: could you show what contains inside providers variable?

Comment: Quick guess: put `providers && ` before `Object.values(...`

Comment: I'm guessing `providers` may be undefined.  Do some debugging and report back.  Perhaps the reason is how you call `getServerSideProps`.  It doesn't do you any good to delay getting your props asynchronously if you need to render now so I'm not sure what you've set up here.

Comment: providers: [
    SpotifyProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: LOGIN_URL,
    }),

Comment: @ChrisG putting providers && before Object.values does not show the error but does not show the text

Comment: That means `providers` is falsey. Did you try logging it?

Comment: Is `login` a page component? `getServerSideProps` only works in page components, it won't run in regular React components.

Comment: Yes it is a page component

Comment: What does `await getProviders()` return inside the `getServerSideProps` function?

Comment: ```export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  };  
}```